# Wget for downloading website text content

Tags: linux, wget

I'm trying to download a content of an online newspaper website, and I need to get one html file for every article. I tried

```
wget -r http://www.anynewspapersite.com
```

but it downloads only indexes of main pages. Is there any attribute of wget I can use to download the html files of articles published in that website?

Comment: Are you sure the articles are linked from the main page? They can be linked from an iframe, they can be linked through javascript... each news site uses a different layout.

Comment: As I see from index.html file, they aren't. In case they are linked through iframe or javascript, can wget help?

Comment: Well, it can, but you have to help wget first :-) You can wget the index, `grep` the links, `sed` them to correct missing parts or parameters, then `wget` the result.